# What function is applied when a List is printed?

Tags: scala, tostring

When I execute this code :

```
object CustomList extends App{

  sealed trait CustomList[+A]
  case object Nil extends CustomList[Nothing]
  case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: CustomList[A]) extends CustomList[A]

  def apply[A](as: A*): CustomList[A] = // Variadic function syntax
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

  val customList : CustomList[Int] = CustomList(1 ,2 ,3)
  println(customList)

  val list : List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
  println(list)
}
```

the following is printed :

```
Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil)))
List(1, 2, 3)
```

`CustomList` is my own implementation of a list data structure and I'm attempting to print similar output when function `println` is applied to it. So instead of `Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil)))` being printed `CustomList(1, 2, 3)` should be printed

The argument to `println` converts argument to string and prints :

```
/**
 * Prints an Object and then terminate the line.  This method calls
 * at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value,
 * then behaves as
 * though it invokes {@link #print(String)} and then
 * {@link #println()}.
 *
 * @param x  The {@code Object} to be printed.
 */
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

But I'm unsure how to create the correct type for to print `CustomList` in the same format.

Is there a method I need to implement to achieve same behavior ?

Comment: You are seeing the current implementation of `toString` that the **Cons** and **Nil** case classes / objects provide. You could override that, a common approach is to define a `mkString` method and in the main trait do this: `override def toString(): String = this.mkString("CustomList(", ", ", ")")` which is more or less the same the stdlib list does. Note that since **String** concatenation is very slow in the JVM, this is one of those cases where IMHO mutability is more than welcome, I would use a **StringBuilder** to implement that `mkString` method.

Comment: Ah I forgot, that `override` should also be `final` to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to turn the `CustomList` into a `String` before printing it?

Here's a *very* non optimal way that you can do that:

```
def show[A](list: CustomList[A]): String = {
    def go(res: String)(as: CustomList[A]): String =
      as match {
        case Nil              => res ++ ")"
        case Cons(head, Nil)  => res ++ head.toString ++ ")"
        case Cons(head, tail) => go(res ++ head.toString ++ ", ")(tail)
      }

    go("CustomList(")(list)
  }
```

I have found out the hard way (i.e. doing project euler problems and having my machine take AGES to finish the computation) that lots of string concatenation in scala is a dreadful idea. But I figured the spirit of the above function may be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `toString` methods

Println Results:

```scala
// Empty
CustomList()
// One Element
CustomList("Test")
// Many Elements
CustomList(false, false, true, true, false)
```

For the `Cons` a recursive auxiliary method can build the string

```scala
case object Nil extends CustomList[Nothing] {
    override def toString: String = "CustomList()"
}

case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: CustomList[A]) extends CustomList[A] {
    def toStringAux: String = {
        tail match {
            case Nil => s"$head"
            case cons: Cons[_] => s"$head, ${cons.toStringAux}"
        }
    }
    
    override def toString: String = {
        s"CustomList($toStringAux)"
    }
}
```

For larger lists, there are performance implications to doing the building of the string like this, and could result in a stackoverflow.

To remedy this you can use the `@tailrec` annotation for `Cons`, but it will require a slightly different signature:

```scala
// In Cons
@tailrec
final def toStringAux(result: String = s"$head"): String = {
    tail match {
        case Nil => s"$result"
        case cons: Cons[A] => cons.toStringAux(s"$result, ${cons.head}")
    }
}

override def toString: String = {
    s"CustomList(${toStringAux()})"
}
```

This will automatically unroll the recursion, resulting in no additional stack creations.

EDIT: if string creation is a concern, simply replace the result with a `StringBuilder`

```scala
// In Cons
@tailrec
final def toStringAux(result: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()): String = {
    result.append(head)
    tail match {
        case Nil => result.mkString(", ")
        case cons: Cons[A] => cons.toStringAux(result)
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

If you want to save the string results, i.e. generate the string once, lazily:

```scala
sealed trait CustomList[+A] {
    lazy val stringValue: String
        // Define toString once, based on a lazy stringValue
    override def toString: String = stringValue
}

case object Nil extends CustomList[Nothing] {
        // Default String
    override lazy val stringValue: String = "CustomList()"
}

case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: CustomList[A]) extends CustomList[A] {
        // Auxiliary String (all the values), with commas separating them
    lazy val auxStringValue: String = tail match {
        case Nil => s"$head"
        case cons: Cons[A] => s"$head, ${cons.auxStringValue}"
    }

    override lazy val stringValue: String = s"CustomList($auxStringValue)"
}
```